# Can't get TinyMCE 4.0.6 to work

Tags: html, tinymce-4

This is driving me crazy....

I'm trying to get TinyMCE v4.0.6 to work, and I'm probably doing something very dumb, since I can't get the editor to display at all.

I could get a v3.5.8 editor to show in a page similar to what follows, but no joy with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>TinyMCE Test</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea"
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="something">
    <textarea name="content" cols="100" rows="15">content</textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I've verified (using FireBug) that the path to the tinymce JavaScript file is correct, but other than that, I'm completely at a loss.

Thanks for any suggestions..

Comment: best way to fix tinymce is to replace it with [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your comment, I took your HTML and checked it with a CDN copy of tinyMCE and it work fine: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mIvFg so I can only assume it's an error with your `tinymce.min.js` file.

Comment: Thanks for this.  However, I've now tried the init script in a multitude of places - (after </html>, after </body>, after </form>, and after </textarea>.  Still no editor.  Also, all the documentation says to put the init script in the <head>, so I'm a bit puzzled that there would be something wrong with the standard structure (esp. cos it's fine with the older version of TinyMCE).

Comment: @ChrisA well, I've stripped out your HTML, used your init and and included a CDN version of tinyMCE and it works: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mIvFg so your issue is most likely with the js file inclusion.

Comment: That was it - I replaced the script line with <script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>, and it just worked straight away.  Thank you!!!

Comment: I have the same problem. It works with the CDN, but if I have it on local it doesn't work. How can I have it on local??